# the same problem as "Android widget different portrait and landscape orientation"

Tags: android, widget, android-widget, screen-orientation

How did you support both landscape and portrait for appwidget? the layout of appwidget will never change when orientate the device from landscape to portrait. by the way, would you please tell me which device support both landscape and portrait for appwidget?

Answer (score 0):

The standard approach is to put the portrait version in **res/layout/**, and the landscape version in **res/layout-land/**, with the same name (e.g., appwidgetmain.xml).

Just refer to it by name (R.layout.appwidgetmain), and Android will choose the correct layout file based on the orientation

Can't answer your seconds part -- too many devices

Answer (score 0):

```
layout/main.xml

layout-land/main.xml
```

`android:layout_width="55dip"` ;

It should use "**dip**" in the file `XML`

If you want the resize widget according to different Screen Size of different Mobile declare

in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<supports-screens   
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true" />
```

If you want know more specific about Screen support follow the link.

[Support Multiple screens](http://d.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

goodluck